# Jasmine2 Stacktrace

Tags: jasmine, protractor, stack-trace, jasmine2.0

When we run our Protractor tests with the jasmine2 framework we get rather useless stack traces such as the following. These are sporadic and never in the same place twice. I can re-run the tests and it'll work just fine.

What exact causes this type of error and how can I go about fixing it?

```
 should log in as admin user and do something (22 secs)
   - Failed: null
     at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Code-Test/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:102:16
     at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Code-Test/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
     at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Code-Test/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
     at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Code-Test/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade `jasmine` to >=2.2 version (2.3 is currently latest), reference:

- [Getting the same stack trace for different errors](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2094)